# Git SSH over NPM behind a proxy not working

Tags: git, ssh, proxy, npm

I'm trying to do a npm install of a project which contains a dependency of a git repository, accessed by ssh.

I'm receiving the following error

```
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/chartjs/color-string.git) fatal:
    unable to connect to github.com:
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (git://github.com/chartjs/color-string.git) github.
    com[0: 192.30.252.122]: errno=Result too large
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
    node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3
npm ERR! code 128
```

If I try the git fetch outside npm it works well, but inside the npm install process it fails.

I have configured and working the `git http.proxy` and `https.proxy` configurations, and I have also a `GIT_SSH` environment variable, public and private keys, `.ssh/config` files for github... etc etc. 
**EDITED:**
I have also configured the npm http and https proxy

It's like npm is overriding my `GIT_SSH` environment variable or the rest of git configuration.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the proxy for the npm not for git.

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Those values are stored inside the `~/.rpmrc` file and used by node to connect and install npm.

Comment: I forgot to tell, that I'd already defined the npm proxy, so that's not the problem. But thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

If you set your proxy settings correctly:

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

Then run Command prompt as an **admin**, when using `npm install`